# Essential kits not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have made a OP kits with essentials. I then tried to make another one. but the other one won't work here's the config for it

```
 May:
    delay: 84600
    items: 
      - 306 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42      respiration:40 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 307 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 308 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 309 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 featherfalling:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 267 1 sharpness:50 fireaspect:30 name:&3&lMay
      - 271 1 sharpness:60 fireaspect:54 knockback:50 name:&4S&6W&eA&2G
```

Anything wrong? And yes I do have unsafe enchantments set to true

Comment: In your `config.yml` file, do you have `unsafe-enchantments = true` set? Otherwise, it won't let you set enchantment levels above the normal limit. Other than that, your formatting looks okay in general.

Comment: @user74676 Try removing the extra spaces between `fireprotection:42` and `respiration:40`

Answer (score 1):

The error when you add a second kit in the essentials config that nothing works is likely because of the wrong format, here is an example how it should look like:

```
 May:
    delay: 84600
    items: 
      - 306 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42      respiration:40 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 307 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 308 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 309 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 featherfalling:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 267 1 sharpness:50 fireaspect:30 name:&3&lMay
      - 271 1 sharpness:60 fireaspect:54 knockback:50 name:&4S&6W&eA&2G
 May2:
    delay: 84600
    items: 
      - 306 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42      respiration:40 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 307 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 308 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 309 1 protection:45 fireprotection:42 featherfalling:42 thorns:40 name:&3&lMay
      - 267 1 sharpness:50 fireaspect:30 name:&3&lMay
      - 271 1 sharpness:60 fireaspect:54 knockback:50 name:&4S&6W&eA&2G
```

Now, whats the REAL trick? its simple, almost EVERY plugin config is in the YML language, a programming language fixed on readability.

before the names, you might have tabstops.... DO NOT HAVE TABSTOPS, instead, use spaces, since the YML language recognizes a difference inbetween tabs and spaces.